# Mobilefirst 8.0 Session timeout implementation

Tags: session, timeout, ibm-mobilefirst, implementation

In My application login and transactions after login are implemented using Mobilefirst 8.0. And I have implemented challenge handler and security test with 60 sec timeout for authentication. My application is getting a session timeout after 60 sec from the time of login even while doing transaction also.

How to reset session timeout for each request to server?

Comment: Where have you set the timeout to 60 seconds? Is this only in the securitycheck? What is the timeout value set for the token?

Comment: it has default value 3600 Sec

Comment: And what is 60 seconds in the securitycheck ? Is it the successtate expiration value?

Comment: Yes, it successtate expiration

Comment: Can you capture a network trace while the issue is recreated and provide it. This should tell us what is happening

Comment: please copy any relevant info to the question. it doesnt belong in the edit section