# Mobilefirst 8 extend login timeout by acquiring resource / manual trigger

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Platform: ionic 3

Objective:
For protected resources, there's a scope to protected with security checking with timeout.
Beside kicking out user when idling like 1 min, **refresh login session(access token?) after each adapter call**.
If better, can refresh login session with a call.

---

Finding:
Tried `obtainAccessToken` and insert that in `WLResourceRequest`.
To me, it just uses `Remember Me Duration` instead of `Success State Expiration`.
But after `Remember Me Duration`, it still logout without updating login session.

---

This is a duplicate of [Mobilefirst 8.0 Session timeout implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47174990/mobilefirst-8-0-session-timeout-implementation)
 as there is no final solution.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

IBM MobileFirst released special type of token called Refresh token which can be used to obtain a new access token when the access token expires.The refresh tokens are long-lived tokens and remain valid for a longer duration of time compared to access tokens.

Enabling refresh tokens feature :

Refresh token feature can be enabled using the following properties on client side and server side respectively.

`client-side property
 File name.: mfpclient.properties
 Property name: wlEnableRefreshToken
 Property value: true`
 For example,
 `wlEnableRefreshToken=true`

server-side property
File name: server.xml
Property name: mfp.security.refreshtoken.enabled.apps
Property value: application bundle id separated by ‘;’

For example,

```
        <jndiEntry jndiName="mfp/mfp.security.refreshtoken.enabled.apps" value='"com.sample.android.myapp1;com.sample.android.myapp2"'/>
```

Use different bundle ids for different platforms.

For more details, refer:[Refresh token](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/#refresh-tokens)

NOTE: This feature available from from [8.0.0.0-MFPF-IF201711230641-CDUpdate-01](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2018/07/24/8-0-cd-update-release/#what-is-included-in-this-cd-update) and only in Android ,soon this feature will be available for iOS as well.

Comment: Have checked out this feature before. "Android only" comes to my concern that it would not be feasible as the app supports iOS and Android. I believe there is a common approach in OAuth / JAX-RS to handle this kind of refreshing / extending login state.

Comment: Refresh token support for  iOS is currently under development, but this can not stop you using this feature only in Android,you can have this feature Android alone ,this does not affect any of your iOS app functionalities.

Comment: I believe with effort it is possible to handle login timeout custom manipulation. Hope to see more advice