# what is the function of access token in mobilefirst 8

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ibm-mobilefirst

At first, i expected access token to be necessary while communicating with WL resource.

**Expected flow**:
1. `WLAuthorizationManager.login(this.securityCheck ,{'username':username, 'password':password, rememberMe: true}).then(`
2. `WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken(this.securityCheck).then(`
3. `let resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest('someURL', WLResourceRequest.GET)`
`resourceRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);`
4. 
`resourceRequest.send().then(`
*where 1 = login, 2 = get access token, 3 = add access token to header, 4 = access resource*

**However**, i find that **without 2, 3**, i can **still** access the resource.
It comes to my concern what is the meaning of `obtainAccessToken` and add `Authorization` header.

Is there any token auto bound to `WLResourceRequest` after `login`?
Is there other way to login without using `WLAuthorizationManager.login`?
If ok, how to let server know the user logged in like using `WLAuthorizationManager.login`?
If the above is true, after custom login, can obtain access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some background about these methods and their working:

> WLAuthorizatonManager.login(securityCheck, credentials) logs into a
>   specified security check. This method does not create an OAuth token.

More details about [WLAuthorizatonManager.login(securityCheck, credentials)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WLAuthorizationManager.html#login).

> WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken(scope) returns an OAuth token
>   containing the specified scope.If the scope is mapped to a security check, it will trigger a corresponding challenge, which the client will have to handle to obtain the token. If obtainAccessToken(scope) is invoke after a successful login(securitycheck) call and if the scope is mapped to the same securitycheck, then you will not see a challenge. The OAuth token will be granted.

More details about [obtainAccessToken()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WLAuthorizationManager.html#obtainAccessToken).

> WLResourceRequest object is used to send a request to any protected or
>   unprotected resource using an absolute or relative URL.
>   WLResourceRequest object automatically handles the MobileFirst
>   OAuth-based security model protocol and invokes the required
>   challenges.

Details about [WLResourceRequest](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WLResourceRequest.html).

To answer your questions:

- Is there any token auto bound to WLResourceRequest after login?

  As mentioned earlier, WLResourceRequest automatically negotiates an OAuth token from MFP server containing the scope that protects the endpoint it is accessing. This may include multiple rounds of OAuth negotiation and also invoke the challenge handlers to handle challenges originating from the server. Once the right token has been obtained, the API automatically adds the token to the request in an 'Authorization' header.
- Is there other way to login without using WLAuthorizationManager.login?

  Instead of WLAuthorizatonManager.login(securityCheck, credentials), if a protected resource is accessed via WLResourceRequest or if WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken(scope) is invoked for a scope that is mapped to a security check, this will trigger a challenge response cycle that will end with a user identity and a token.
- If ok, how to let server know the user logged in like using WLAuthorizationManager.login(securityCheck, credentials)?

  MFP runtime takes care of this - regardless of if the user identity is set via WLAuthorizatonManager.login() or if WLResourceRequest / WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken(scope) triggers a challenge response cycle that goes through the securitychecl.
- If the above is true, after custom login, can obtain access token?

  Not sure what you mean by 'custom login', but you can always obtain an OAuth token using WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken(scope) or WLResourceRequest. The difference is that obtainAccessToken() will get you a token for the scope you specify, while WLResourceRequest will invoke an endpoint by obtaining an OAuth token covering all the required scopes automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. So i assume preemptive login takes care of obtainAccessToken and resource request header

Comment: By custom login, i mean if there's a way to set up a end point to simulate WLAuthorizationManager.login directs to and return access token so that later access token can be added to resource request header. Indeed, this is the implementation of a project i saw(i have no access to server side). Connection to server using WLResourceRequest with no login and obtainAccessToken call. My ultimate goal is to implement a login while every resource call would extend login timeout. hope to see your advice also.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52256444/mobilefirst-8-extend-login-timeout-by-acquiring-resource-manual-trigger/52256975?noredirect=1#comment91510266_52256975

Comment: i see no solution out there

Comment: Pre-emptive login does not give you a token. In this case, after successful login, you can either call obtainAccessToken for a specific scope or call WLResourceRequest().

Comment: On the extending timeout - this is possible for OAuth tokens on Android , with Refresh tokens. This extension is independent of the login success state. SecurityCheck's success state does not extend. It will end when the configured value expires. There after a challenge will be issued.

Comment: Thanks again. So for normal apps like maybe banking, the behavior should be like what i mentioned. Login > idle > timeout or login > transaction ... How should this be implemented using mobilefirst?

Comment: Correct. This is the default behaviour as well. MFP Security checks come with a default successstate of 60 seconds. You can extend this to a reasonable period. And client side logic can keep a timer that can invoke a logout call to ensure the previous security context is properly discarded.