# mobilefirst cannot delete confidential client

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

using mobilefirst client 8.0.0.00-20180817-042259
on WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5.8 Liberty

added a confidential client named `Push`
after initial setup of allowed scope,
it cannot be modified and deleted.
[image: confidential client]

`test, admin, push` as predefined confidential client.
Is that case-sensitive?
Or a mobilefirst bug?
Or any other settings to edit the client?

Comment: Consider adding the exact MFP version and the application server on which you are running.

Comment: How did you "add" the custom 'Push' confidential client? Directly in the console or did customer edit the JNDI or environment entries to add the confidential client?

Comment: Directly in the console

Comment: I don't have the exact same version, but a build level older and newer does not recreate the issue. Are you possibly running on Windows?

Comment: Yes, install using mobilefirst developer kit https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/ on windows. This is triggered when adding client for pushing notification

Comment: just checked out you are good at mobilefirst. Would you happen to know how to refresh user timeout by every call to adapter / user can never be logged out automatically by timeout

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52256444/mobilefirst-8-extend-login-timeout-by-acquiring-resource-manual-trigger/52256975?noredirect=1#comment91510266_52256975

Comment: This would be using Refresh tokens. The feature is available on Android at the moment. The work on iOS refresh token is in progress.